# Django Channels group_send ~30s delay before sending

Tags: django, django-channels

I'm trying to send two messages in succession from an `AsyncJsonWebSocketConsumer` to a group via `group_send`. My problem is that only one message to one client is delivered immediately, while the other messages are delivered roughly 30s later. If I only send one of the two messages, all messages are delivered immediately.

I have set up a minimal example. The consumer sends back the message it received, but adds two timestamps `server_received` and `server_sent` when it receives and sends the message, respectively.

```py
class TestConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.channel_layer.group_add('TESTGROUP', self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

    async def receive_json(self, content):
        content['server_received'] = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')

        await self.channel_layer.group_send('TESTGROUP', {'type': 'send_message', 'message': content})
        # delayed only if sending two messages
        #await self.channel_layer.group_send('TESTGROUP', {'type': 'send_message', 'message': content})

    async def send_message(self, event):
        await self.send_json({**event['message'], 'server_sent': datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')})
```

Here's some Javascript creating two connections and sending an initial message from the second websocket. (I know it's not super safe to do it this way, because we don't know in what state `ws1` is, when sending, so we could drop a few messages, but doesn't matter for our purposes)

```js
function fmtDate(date) { return date.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', {timeZone: 'UTC'}) }

var ws1 = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/test/')
ws1.onmessage = (event) => { 
    var msg = JSON.parse(event.data)
    const now = new Date()
    msg.client_received = fmtDate(now)
    console.log('WS1', msg)
}
var ws2 = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/test/')
ws2.onmessage = (event) => {
    var msg = JSON.parse(event.data)
    const now = new Date()
    msg.client_received = fmtDate(now)
    console.log('WS2', msg)
}

ws2.onopen = function() {
    const now = new Date()
    ws1.send(JSON.stringify({client_sent: fmtDate(now)})) 
}
```

When only sending back 1 message from the consumer (like the code I posted above) the result looks like this

```
WS1 {client_sent: "11:58:29", server_received: "11:58:29", server_sent: "11:58:29", client_received: "11:58:29"}
WS2 {client_sent: "11:58:29", server_received: "11:58:29", server_sent: "11:58:29", client_received: "11:58:29"}
```

When sending two messages (uncommenting the second group_send)

```
WS2 {client_sent: "12:00:05", server_received: "12:00:05", server_sent: "12:00:05", client_received: "12:00:05"}
WS1 {client_sent: "12:00:05", server_received: "12:00:05", server_sent: "12:00:35", client_received: "12:00:35"}
WS2 {client_sent: "12:00:05", server_received: "12:00:05", server_sent: "12:00:35", client_received: "12:00:35"}
WS1 {client_sent: "12:00:05", server_received: "12:00:05", server_sent: "12:00:35", client_received: "12:00:35"}
```

Edit:
It seems that the redis server is the cause. Problem does not occur when using `InMemoryChannelLayer` instead of redis

Comment: Since it only happens on the first message, I suspect it has something to do with the redis connection being created at that time. After the first message, the connection is already there and everything goes smoothly. Though I'm not sure why it only happens when sending back a single message. Have you tried this multiple times to ascertain it happens constantly? Send more messages from the front and check

Comment: Hi Lukas and @Ken4scholars - how did you solve this, please? Facing a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172488/django-channels-group-send-getting-delayed-while-sending-to-active-window-whe)

Comment: If I send only 1 message, there's no problem. If I send multiple, the first one gets delayed and the rest follow smoothly. This doesn't happen while using InMemoryChannelLayer. But we need to use Redis for production, so I'll be grateful to learn how you solved this, please.